# Unable to start apache phoenix over hbase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am unable to start apache phoenix installed over hbase.
I get below error when i try to execute the py file.
Please advise

[image]

Comment: Can you provide details of the phoenix installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like python version issue. Your default version seems to be Python 3 and phoenix has syntax of Python 2.

The shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/env python` and it is getting python 3. Make appropriate changes to set python 2 as default.